# NSMutableDictionary treats NSString value as NSNumber

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary, nsnumber

I have the following value in a NSMutableDictionary - see image

[image]

I'm attempting to get at "a" thus:

```
let a = dictionary.objectForKey("a") as! String
```

the app crashes at this point with

**Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x...) to 'NSString' (0x...).**

other numbers inside "" are treated as strings as are numbers outside of strings cast to String without any issue.

Can anyone let me know what's going on? And how to get at these values easily?

Comment: Is the dictionary {"a":"-1"} and your code block a mistype?

Comment: You can use the `is` keyword to check the type before casting e.g. `let isString = dictionary["a"] is String`

Comment: yes - I've just tested and it's the de-bugger that is wrapping the quotes around the -1. I had thought it was storing a string but it isn't...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The value is an `NSNumber`, not an `NSString`. You can use `stringValue` to convert it:

```
if let a = d["a"] as? NSNumber {
    let aString = a.stringValue
    println(aString) // -1
} else {
    // either d doesn't have a value for the key "a", or d does but the value is not an NSNumber
}
```

If you're sure it exists and is an `NSNumber`, you can use forced unwrapping, forced casting, and string interpolation:

```
let a = d["a"]! as! NSNumber
let aString = "\(a)"
```

Comment: This is a fantastic workaround for a bug I discovered in Xcode 7.1. Thank you! I discovered the pattern recognition doesn't seem to work as it has in past versions of Xcode. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-search_navigator/UsingPatternsWhenSearching/UsingPatternsWhenSearching.html